# Javascript reduce(), passing in initial value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm working through an exercise using the underscore library to perform a count of item occurrences.

Specifically, I have this array:

```
products = [
       { name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
       { name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
    ];
```

And am trying to use map(), flatten() and reduce() to determine the number of times each ingredient shows up.

When I use the code below, ingredientCount returns undefined values:

```
var ingredientCount = { "{ingredient name}": 0 };

    _(products).chain()
    .map(function(obj) {return obj.ingredients;})
    .flatten().reduce(function(memo, x) {
      return memo[x] = (memo[x] || 0) + 1;
    }, ingredientCount)
    .value();
```

However, if I remove the second argument to reduce() and include the initial object in the function body, everything works as expected, i.e.:

var ingredientCount = { "{ingredient name}": 0 };

```
_(products).chain()
.map(function(obj) {return obj.ingredients;})
.flatten().reduce(function(memo, x) {
  return ingredientCount[x] = (ingredientCount[x] || 0) + 1;
})
.value();
```

Can somebody help explain why this is the case?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you are using reduce...the reduce function will return  asingle value what you want is teh sum of all ingredients individually something like this _"{"artichoke":1,"sundried tomatoes":2,"mushrooms":2,"roma":1,"goats cheese":1,"rosemary":1,"black beans":1,"jalapenos":1,"blue cheese":1,"garlic":1,"walnuts":1,"spinach":1,"kalamata olives":1,"sesame seeds":1}"_

Comment: @Cyril—the accumulator can be an Object (i.e. the value can be an object reference).

Comment: Yes you are right but when i applied Jaromanda answer to the above problem i got a single result...not what is expected..your answer works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return memo[x] = (memo[x] || 0) + 1;` returns a number for the next iteration of the loop to use as memo.

instead do

```
memo[x] = (memo[x] || 0) + 1;
return memo;
```

if you **really** want to do it in a single statement

```
return memo[x] = (memo[x] || 0) + 1, memo;
```

Comment: This is the second question I've seen today where someone made essentially the same mistake with `reduce`.

Comment: I think there's some sort of mass shared consciousness thing happening on SO - you see clusters of almost the same problem come up occasionally. the batch of fizzbuzz and tic-tac-toe questions is almost due :p

Answer (score 1):

Always interesting to see a plain JS alternative:

```
var counts = p.reduce(function(acc, prod) {
  prod.ingredients.forEach(function(i) {
    acc[i] = (acc[i] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return acc;
},{});
```

which seems lot clearer, though in a general case it's better to use:

```
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(i)) acc[i] = 0;
  acc[i]++
```

for the counter part.

```js
products = [
       { name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
       { name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
       { name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
    ];
    
function countIngredients(p) {
  var counts = p.reduce(function(acc, prod) {
    prod.ingredients.forEach(function(i) {
      acc[i] = (acc[i] || 0) +1;
    })
    return acc;
  },{})
  return counts;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(countIngredients(products)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this in underscore

```js
    products = [
           { name: "Sonoma", ingredients: ["artichoke", "sundried tomatoes", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
           { name: "Pizza Primavera", ingredients: ["roma", "sundried tomatoes", "goats cheese", "rosemary"], containsNuts: false },
           { name: "South Of The Border", ingredients: ["black beans", "jalapenos", "mushrooms"], containsNuts: false },
           { name: "Blue Moon", ingredients: ["blue cheese", "garlic", "walnuts"], containsNuts: true },
           { name: "Taste Of Athens", ingredients: ["spinach", "kalamata olives", "sesame seeds"], containsNuts: true }
        ];
    ingredientCount = {};

    _(products).chain()
        .map(function(obj) {return obj.ingredients;}).flatten().each(function(memo, x) {
       ingredientCount[memo] = (ingredientCount[memo] || 0) + 1;
    });

    document.write(JSON.stringify(ingredientCount));

    //this will produce this "{"artichoke":1,"sundried tomatoes":2,"mushrooms":2,"roma":1,"goats cheese":1,"rosemary":1,"black beans":1,"jalapenos":1,"blue cheese":1,"garlic":1,"walnuts":1,"spinach":1,"kalamata olives":1,"sesame seeds":1}"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```